# Use list comprehension to create a list of strings put together using dict values

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts that look like this:

```
{
    "address": "TestA",
    "zipcode": "95723",
    "postofficename": "TestB"
}
```

I would like to do a list comprehension that creates a list of strings that starts with an input parameter called `address`:

```
[
    "TestA, 95723 TestB"
]
```

I cannot seem to get it to work, and not sure where to go from here, what I tried:

```
startswith_list = \
        [r = '{}, {} {}'.format(r['address'], r['zipcode'], r['postofficename']) if r['address'].startswith(address) for r in result]
```

Comment: `r = ...` at the beginning of the comprehension is a syntax error. The first thing should be an expression, like `'{}, {} {}'.format(r['address'], r['zipcode'], r['postofficename'])`

Comment: @ForceBru okay, but simply removing the "r = ..." does not solve the issue, add an answer if you know how to solve this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mistakes here:

```
[r = '{}, {} {}'.format(r['address'], r['zipcode'], r['postofficename']) if r['address'].startswith(address) for r in result]
```

First, the `r = ...` is a syntax error because the first thing in the comprehension must be an expression, like this:

```
['{}, {} {}'.format(r['address'], r['zipcode'], r['postofficename']) if r['address'].startswith(address) for r in result]
```

Next, the `if` is in the wrong place: it should come *after* the loop:

```
['{}, {} {}'.format(r['address'], r['zipcode'], r['postofficename']) for r in result if r['address'].startswith(address)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax errors are due to having `[r = ...` at the start of the list comprehension and the `if` before the `for`. Also I would generally avoid using the  backslash for line continuations. The square brackets work nicely to break up your code, see below.

Bonus points: using [format_map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) to format the dict into the string

```py
startswith_list = [
    '{address}, {zipcode} {postofficename}'.format_map(r)
    for r in result
    if r['address'].startswith(address) 
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want list comprehension with condition you need to place at end not in middle, that is in your case:

```
result = [{"address": "TestA", "zipcode": "95723", "postofficename": "TestB"}]
address = "Test"
startswith_list = ['{}, {} {}'.format(r['address'], r['zipcode'], r['postofficename']) for r in result if r['address'].startswith(address)]
print(startswith_list)  # ['TestA, 95723 TestB']
```

you might also consider using so-called *f-strings*, if you are using python version 3.6 or higher and have control over input (or know that there will be not malicious input). In this case:

```
startswith_list = [f"{r['address']}, {r['zipcode']} {r['postofficename']}" for r in result if r['address'].startswith(address)]
```